# Another inequality $a+b+c\le\sum\limits_{cyc}a\lambda^{b-c}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> $a+b+c\le\sum\limits_{cyc}a\lambda^{b-c}$ with $a,b,c,\lambda>0$

Since $\lambda^{b-c}+\lambda^{c-a}+\lambda^{a-b}\ge 3$ it would be enough if I could show that,

$2\left(a\lambda^{b-c}\right)\ge a\lambda^{c-a}+a\lambda^{a-b}$

but I think in general this does not hold, one has to consider the sum, i.e.

$2\sum\limits_{cyc}a\lambda^{b-c}\ge \sum\limits_{cyc}a\lambda^{c-a}+\sum\limits_{cyc}a\lambda^{a-b}$

or is this approach not useful ?

Comment: Try Jensen inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @geromty mentioned in the comment, Jenson's inequality implies
$$\sum_\text{cyc}\frac a{a+b+c}\lambda^{b-c}\ge\lambda^{\sum\limits_\text{cyc}(ab-ac)/(a+b+c)}=1$$